# When using keras and trying to train my model on my GPU my program shuts down because "Integer value: x is too large". How do I fix this?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

```
# Create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(4, activation="sigmoid"))

model.layers[-6].trainable = False
model.summary()


model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

train = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=50, batch_size=32, verbose=1)
```

I have borrowed some code and I am trying to train a model to read licence plates, but as stated in the title I get a integer than is out of bounds for int32. I do not get this problem if I remove a Cudnn library s.t the training is done on the CPU. If anyone recognizes the problem and know how to fix it that would be really helpful!

ps: I am using Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019 community, CUDA11.2, and the most recent Cudnn on a Intel and Nvidia RTX system

Comment: Try to run the same code on google colab using GPU runtime. Tensorflow officially support `cuDNN 8.0` and `CUDA 11.0` for the `Tensorflow 2.4`. Check the compatible version before training your model. Thanks!